# Figuring out probability ellipse from covariance matrix

Tags: c++, geometry, eigen3

I'm trying to reverse engineer our data to what apparently should be probability ellipse. As an input I get a struct which contains cryptic members, notably meanX, meanY, Co00, Co01 and Co10. I guess x and y are center of the ellipse, and CoXX are covariance matrix. Sounds like I should employ eigenvalues and eigenvector to find out two radiuses of the ellipse. I found the [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) c++ library, however I have a difficulty to figure out what I have to do with Eigen computation results when I get the vectors and values back. How do I find two radiuses and the ellipse tilt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let:

```
m = (meanX)
    (meanY)
```

be the (vector) mean and:

```
S = (Co00 Co01)
    (Co01 Co11)
```

be the covariance matrix of the data. The center of the ellipse is `m`, the axes of the ellipse are the eigenvectors `e1` and `e2` of the matrix `S` (the minor axis `e1` is associated to the smallest eigenvalue of `S`). The radii are proportional to `sqrt(λ1)` and `sqrt(λ2)` where `λ1` and `λ2` are the eigenvalues associated to `e1` and `e2`. Finally the tilt of the ellipse is `atan2(e2_y, e2_x)` (angle between the major axis and the `x` axis).

This all comes from diagonalizing the matrix S and expanding the expression `(X - m)^T S^-1 (X - m) = 1` to match the expected form `(x / a)^2 + (y / b)^2 = 1`. Note that the radii should be scaled if one is looking at specific confidence level, for 95% confidence, the scaling factor is `sqrt(5.911)`.

With Eigen, the following piece of code should work:

```
#include <Eigen/Eigenvalues>

// [...]

Vector2d m;
Matrix2d S;

m << meanX, meanY;
S << Co00, Co01, Co01, Co11;

SelfAdjointEigenSolver<Matrix2d> solver(S);
double l1 = solver.eigenvalues().x();
double l2 = solver.eigenvalues().y();
Vector2d e1 = solver.eigenvectors().col(0);
Vector2d e2 = solver.eigenvectors().col(1);

double scale95 = sqrt(5.991);
double R1 = scale95 * sqrt(l1);
double R2 = scale95 * sqrt(l2);
double tilt = atan2(e2.y(), e2.x());
```

Comment: You are the man! Looks like it works and gives the same output I get with OpenCV. Thank you!

Comment: I think it is better to add eigenvalue(l1,l2) comparison before calculating tilt since radian value calculating based on eigenvector which corresponds to largest eigenvalue;

  if (l2 >= l1)
  {
   double tilt= atan2(e2.y(), e2.x());
  }
  else
  {
   double tilt= atan2(e1.y(), e1.x());
  }